# Checking to see if string has been parsed after event has occured?

Tags: java, swing, event-handling, joptionpane, parseint

I'm trying to make sure that the first character the user enters in this textbox is a letter. If it isn't, however, there will be a message box pop-up notifying the user that the first character cannot be a number, and must be a number. The problem is that the program completely ignores the code after the event occurs to check and see if there is a letter in the first position.

```
if (event.getSource() == item2)
        {
            string = String.format("Account number: %s", event.getActionCommand());

            str = string.substring(1);

            try{
                Integer.parseInt(string.substring(0,1));
                parsable = true;
            }catch(NumberFormatException e){
                parsable = false;
            }
            if(parsable == true)
            {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "ENTER THE LETTER CORRESPONDING WITH YOUR ACCOUNT NUMBER AS THE FIRST CHARACTER IN THE TEXT FIELD.");
            }
            /*
            try
            {
                Integer.parseInt(str);
            }
            catch(NumberFormatException e)
            {
                String.format("enter a valid number");
            }
            */
        }
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

because you are using String.format("Account.... your string's first character will always be 'A' of Account you have to check on String which you recived from event.getActionCommand() mathod